# Redefining dot notation for Association

Tags: associations

I'm trying to use Associations as object, and specifically want to use them as they are used in other languages using the dot notation.
I'm using the code below to get started.

```
Unprotect[Dot];
Dot[a_Association, p_Symbol] :=
  Return[Evaluate[ a[p]]];
Protect[Dot];
```

This works fine for many things.

```
a=<|firstName->"Joe",lastName->"Smith",age->20|>;
a.firstName
(* Joe *)
```

But, it does not work for other things

```
a.age^2
a.firstName <> " " <> a.lastName
```

I know there are things I can do to resolve this issue, but the best way is eluding me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This happens because `Precedence[Dot]` is fairly low compared to that of `Power` and `StringJoin`. For example, `(a.age)^2` and `(a.firstName) <> " " <> (a.lastName)` will work. I don't know exactly how the precedence should be changed, though.

Comment: `.` has very low precedence in WL: [tutorial/OperatorInputForms](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OperatorInputForms.html) way too low for an access operator. You can put `()` around but that is not a point. I'd say it is impossible in MMA because you don't have access to FE parser and patching Kernel parser will be a huge task.  `a.age^2` is automatically `RowBox[{"a", ".", 
  RowBox[{"age", "^", "2"}]}]]` so you are not even starting from a plain input form string but already structured input.

Comment: Thanks Sjoerd & Kuba.  I didn't realize it was a precedence issue.  For now, parentheses may suffice.

Comment: Would you be satisfied with a solution where you use an input alias to enter the dot? For example, <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>.</kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd>?

Comment: Thanks for asking, Carl.  Yes, I'd be happy to give it a try.

Comment: `a@age^2` seems good enough to me.  C has an [obfuscated code contest](https://www.ioccc.org).  Maybe WTC should have one, too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are willing to use input aliases to enter the dot, you could do:

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[],{InputAliases,"."}] = TemplateBox[
    {},
    "Accessor",
    DisplayFunction->("."&),
    InterpretationFunction:>("@"&),
    SyntaxForm->"@"
];
```

Note that this overrides the standard alias for \[CenterDot]. Your association:

```
a=<|firstName->"Joe",lastName->"Smith",age->20|>;
```

Then, in the following, I use <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>.</kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd> instead of just <kbd>.</kbd>:

```
a.firstName
a.age^2
a.firstName <> " " <> a.lastName
```

> "Joe"

> 400

> "Joe Smith"

Comment: Nice!   Works nice, without a lot of extra keystrokes, and still has the 'look' I was striving for.  Thanks!